# get success message after smtpclose

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using an ajax call to send emails with phpmailer. When the php script send mails and returns message i noticed that this below function stop the success function

```
    public function __destruct()
    {
        //Close any open SMTP connection nicely
        $this->smtpClose();
    }
```

on my php script the last code lone is

```
echo json_encode($valid);
```

Is there a way to close smtp before message return ?

Comment: Just call `$mailer->smtpClose();` from your code?

Comment: That code doesn’t cause your issue, it’s something else. Take a look at the Ajax sending example provided with PHPMailer

Comment: When i stop calling the php mailler script the ajax call works just fine . Now when i insert the $mailer->smtpClose(); before the json echo the script just stop whitout sending response to ajax call